Is it possible to use Oracle Edition-Based Redefinition in AWS RDS?
I have an Oracle Database on AWS RDS.
I would like to use Oracle Edition-Based Redefinition :
I'm doing something like :
-- Create a function in the default edition of the database
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 1;
END;


-- Create a new edition
CREATE EDITION E2;
ALTER SESSION SET EDITION = e2;

-- Change the function in edition 2
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 2;
END;

-- Test the function in the context of the new edition 
select test from dual;    -- returns 2 as expected

-- Test the function in the context of the default edition
ALTER SESSION SET EDITION = ora$base;
select test from dual;    -- returns 1 as expected

Now let's say I want to move to the new edition (a release for example for all db objects) :
ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT EDITION = e2;

I'm getting the error ORA-01031 - Insufficient privileges.
I'm using the database admin user provided by AWS RDS which is not as powerful as sysdba user.
So my question is : is it possible Oracle Edition-Based Redefinition in AWS RDS ?

Well, the answer is yes. It's possible. The answer is here
